# Why does my Makefile with pattern rules not create debugging symbols for main?

Tags: makefile

I am using this auto-generated Makefile with pattern rules, that I oviously do not understand yet. I want to create debuggins symbols and then debug main, but it doesn't work. There is a `-g` flag. Adding `$(LDFLAGS)` statement above after `$(ODIR)` does not print one as expcted.

```
IDIR =./include                                                                                                                                             
CC=g++                                                                                                                                                      
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)                                                                                                                                          
LDFLAGS = -g                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                            
ODIR=./                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                            
LIBS=                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                            
_OBJ = main.o                                                                                                                                             
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                            
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c                                                                                                                                            
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                            
main: $(OBJ)                                                                                                                                              
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                            
.PHONY: clean                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                            
clean:                                                                                                                                                      
        rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

This is the terminal output

```
g++    -c -o Source.o Source.cpp                                                                                    
g++ -g -o Source Source.o -I./include
```

Comment: The `-g` option is a _compiler_ option, not a linker option.  The linker can't put debugging symbols into the final executable if the compiler doesn't generate debugging symbols!

Comment: I tried it in CFLAGS as well. Also didn’t work

Comment: Please cut and paste the make command you invoked and the output you got (not a screenshot), with formatting.  Do you see the `-g` option in the compile line?  Also you say "but it doesn't work"; that is not a problem description we can help with.  Please be more precise about the problem you're having.

Comment: @MadScientist I added them below

Comment: So when I change ``_OBJ`` from ``main.o`` to ``main.cpp`` it works. But usually you specify the object files to build and not the source files afaik

Comment: NB: you have a rule for building `.o` files from `.c` files, but your actual source is a `.cpp` file!

Comment: @Alnitak: That's it! Such a careless mistake...

Comment: FWIW, that compilation from `.cpp` to `.o` was using (GNU?) make's implicit rules for compiling C++ files.   IIRC, these would include use of `CXX` instead of `CC` to invoke the compiler, and `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sources are C++ (.cpp) but your Makefile contains explicit instructions for building *C* files.  Make is therefore falling back to its built in implicit rules.

Also note that by convention those rules use `$(CXX)` to refer to the C++ compiler, with `$(CXXFLAGS)` replacing `$(CFLAGS)`, and the `-I` flag belongs in `$(CPPFLAGS)`:

```
IDIR =./include
CPPFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)
CXXFLAGS = -g
ODIR=.
LIBS=

_OBJ = main.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<

main:   $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

If you were to do away with the `ODIR` handling and use the conventional variable names you could do without the explicit `.o: .cpp` rule altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this as a Makefile template. It doesn’t cover everything but is a good start.